# Find vms exceeding disk limit using ansible

Tags: ansible

How to use conditional query on "capacity_in_kb" to print VM names utilizing defined limit in the play?

Following is the disk_info results output,

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
            "changed": false, 
            "failed": false, 
            "guest_disk_info": {
                "0": {
                    "backing_datastore": "DatastoreA", 
                    "backing_eagerlyscrub": false, 
                    "backing_filename": "[DatastoreA] server1/server1.vmdk", 
                    "backing_thinprovisioned": true, 
                    "backing_type": "FlatVer2", 
                    "backing_uuid": "6100C29a-af30-ebe4-0c68-e72d60481103", 
                    "backing_writethrough": false, 
                    "capacity_in_bytes": 214748364800, 
                    "capacity_in_kb": 209715200, 
                    "controller_bus_number": 0, 
                    "controller_key": 1000, 
                    "controller_type": "lsilogicsas", 
                    "key": 2000, 
                    "label": "Hard disk 1", 
                    "summary": "209,715,200 KB", 
                    "unit_number": 0
                }
            }, 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "datacenter": "/DatacenterA", 
                    "folder": "/vm/server2", 
                    "hostname": "vmware.server.example.com", 
                    "moid": null, 
                    "name": "server1", 
                    "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
                    "port": 443, 
                    "proxy_host": null, 
                    "proxy_port": null, 
                    "use_instance_uuid": false, 
                    "servername": "server2", 
                    "uuid": null, 
                    "validate_certs": false
                }
            }, 
            "item": "server1"
        }, 
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
            "changed": false, 
            "failed": false, 
            "guest_disk_info": {
                "0": {
                    "backing_datastore": "DatastoreA", 
                    "backing_eagerlyscrub": false, 
                    "backing_filename": "[DatastoreA] server2/server2.vmdk", 
                    "backing_thinprovisioned": false, 
                    "backing_type": "FlatVer2", 
                    "backing_uuid": "6000D296-4d2a-abf0-5d21-0cfcdf2498ad", 
                    "backing_writethrough": false, 
                    "capacity_in_bytes": 37580963840, 
                    "capacity_in_kb": 36700160, 
                    "controller_bus_number": 0, 
                    "controller_key": 1000, 
                    "controller_type": "lsilogicsas", 
                    "key": 2000, 
                    "label": "Hard disk 1", 
                    "summary": "36,700,160 KB", 
                    "unit_number": 0
                }
            }, 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "datacenter": "/DatacenterA", 
                    "folder": "/vm/server2", 
                    "hostname": "vmware.server.example.com", 
                    "moid": null, 
                    "name": "server2", 
                    "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
                    "port": 443, 
                    "proxy_host": null, 
                    "proxy_port": null, 
                    "use_instance_uuid": false, 
                    "servername": "server2", 
                    "uuid": null, 
                    "validate_certs": false
                }
            }, 
            "item": "server2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the play I am using,

```
- name: Gather disk info from guests
  vmware_guest_disk_info:
    hostname: "{{ vmware_hostname }}"
    servername: "{{ vmware_servername }}"
    password: "{{ vmware_password }}"
    datacenter: DatacenterA
    validate_certs: no
    name: "{{ item }}"
  register: disk_info
  with_items:
  - server1
  - server2
  - server3

- name: Get disk info of guest VMs
  set_fact:
        vms_disks_info: "{{ disk_info.results | list}}"

- name: Show VMs with disk space more than 60 GB
  assert:
    that:
      - 'disk_info.guest_disk_info["0"].capacity_in_kb <= 62914560'
      - 'disk_info.guest_disk_info["0"].capacity_in_kb >= 0'
    fail_msg: "{{ item }} Disk space is higher must be below 60"
```

I am stuck on how to do conditional check on each host's disk space to get VMs name exceeding disk limit. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Given the output of your `disk_info.results`, it seems that what you are looking for is playbook [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops).

*Deprecation note:* `with_items` would also work, but Ansible plan to deprecate it, see the notes under https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loops.

Also mind that you do **not** need to use the `list` filter on `disk_info.results` as it is already an array usable by `loop`.

```
- name: Get disk info of guest VMs
  set_fact:
    vms_disks_info: "{{ disk_info.results }}"

- name: Show VMs with disk space more than 60GB
  assert:
    that:
      - item.guest_disk_info["0"].capacity_in_kb <= 62914560
      - item.guest_disk_info["0"].capacity_in_kb >= 0
    fail_msg: "{{ item.item }} disk space is too high, it must be below 60GB"
  loop: "{{ vms_disks_info }}"
```

For a faked example, given the playbook

```
- hosts: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars: 
    vms_disks_info: [
      {
        "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "guest_disk_info": {
          "0": {
            "backing_datastore": "DatastoreA", 
            "backing_eagerlyscrub": false, 
            "backing_filename": "[DatastoreA] server1/server1.vmdk", 
            "backing_thinprovisioned": true, 
            "backing_type": "FlatVer2", 
            "backing_uuid": "6100C29a-af30-ebe4-0c68-e72d60481103", 
            "backing_writethrough": false, 
            "capacity_in_bytes": 214748364800, 
            "capacity_in_kb": 209715200, 
            "controller_bus_number": 0, 
            "controller_key": 1000, 
            "controller_type": "lsilogicsas", 
            "key": 2000, 
            "label": "Hard disk 1", 
            "summary": "209,715,200 KB", 
            "unit_number": 0
          }
        }, 
        "invocation": {
          "module_args": {
            "datacenter": "/DatacenterA", 
            "folder": "/vm/server2", 
            "hostname": "vmware.server.example.com", 
            "moid": null, 
            "name": "server1", 
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
            "port": 443, 
            "proxy_host": null, 
            "proxy_port": null, 
            "use_instance_uuid": false, 
            "servername": "server2", 
            "uuid": null, 
            "validate_certs": false
          }
        }, 
        "item": "server1"
      }, 
      {
        "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "guest_disk_info": {
          "0": {
            "backing_datastore": "DatastoreA", 
            "backing_eagerlyscrub": false, 
            "backing_filename": "[DatastoreA] server2/server2.vmdk", 
            "backing_thinprovisioned": false, 
            "backing_type": "FlatVer2", 
            "backing_uuid": "6000D296-4d2a-abf0-5d21-0cfcdf2498ad", 
            "backing_writethrough": false, 
            "capacity_in_bytes": 37580963840, 
            "capacity_in_kb": 36700160, 
            "controller_bus_number": 0, 
            "controller_key": 1000, 
            "controller_type": "lsilogicsas", 
            "key": 2000, 
            "label": "Hard disk 1", 
            "summary": "36,700,160 KB", 
            "unit_number": 0
          }
        }, 
        "invocation": {
          "module_args": {
            "datacenter": "/DatacenterA", 
            "folder": "/vm/server2", 
            "hostname": "vmware.server.example.com", 
            "moid": null, 
            "name": "server2", 
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
            "port": 443, 
            "proxy_host": null, 
            "proxy_port": null, 
            "use_instance_uuid": false, 
            "servername": "server2", 
            "uuid": null, 
            "validate_certs": false
          }
        }, 
        "item": "server2"
      }
    ]

  tasks:
    - name: Show VMs with disk space more than 60GB
      assert:
        that:
          - item.guest_disk_info["0"].capacity_in_kb <= 62914560
          - item.guest_disk_info["0"].capacity_in_kb >= 0
        fail_msg: "{{ item.item }} disk space is too high, it must be below 60GB"
      loop: "{{ vms_disks_info }}"
```

I end up what that recap:

```
PLAY [local] *******************************************************************

TASK [Show VMs with disk space more than 60GB] *********************************
failed: [local] (item={'ansible_loop_var': 'item', 'changed': False, 'failed': False, 'guest_disk_info': {'0': {'backing_datastore': 'DatastoreA', 'backing_eagerlyscrub': False, 'backing_filename': '[DatastoreA] server1/server1.vmdk', 'backing_thinprovisioned': True, 'backing_type': 'FlatVer2', 'backing_uuid': '6100C29a-af30-ebe4-0c68-e72d60481103', 'backing_writethrough': False, 'capacity_in_bytes': 214748364800, 'capacity_in_kb': 209715200, 'controller_bus_number': 0, 'controller_key': 1000, 'controller_type': 'lsilogicsas', 'key': 2000, 'label': 'Hard disk 1', 'summary': '209,715,200 KB', 'unit_number': 0}}, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'datacenter': '/DatacenterA', 'folder': '/vm/server2', 'hostname': 'vmware.server.example.com', 'moid': None, 'name': 'server1', 'password': 'VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER', 'port': 443, 'proxy_host': None, 'proxy_port': None, 'use_instance_uuid': False, 'servername': 'server2', 'uuid': None, 'validate_certs': False}}, 'item': 'server1'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "assertion": "item.guest_disk_info['0'].capacity_in_kb <= 62914560",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "item": {
        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "guest_disk_info": {
            "0": {
                "backing_datastore": "DatastoreA",
                "backing_eagerlyscrub": false,
                "backing_filename": "[DatastoreA] server1/server1.vmdk",
                "backing_thinprovisioned": true,
                "backing_type": "FlatVer2",
                "backing_uuid": "6100C29a-af30-ebe4-0c68-e72d60481103",
                "backing_writethrough": false,
                "capacity_in_bytes": 214748364800,
                "capacity_in_kb": 209715200,
                "controller_bus_number": 0,
                "controller_key": 1000,
                "controller_type": "lsilogicsas",
                "key": 2000,
                "label": "Hard disk 1",
                "summary": "209,715,200 KB",
                "unit_number": 0
            }
        },
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "datacenter": "/DatacenterA",
                "folder": "/vm/server2",
                "hostname": "vmware.server.example.com",
                "moid": null,
                "name": "server1",
                "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "port": 443,
                "proxy_host": null,
                "proxy_port": null,
                "servername": "server2",
                "use_instance_uuid": false,
                "uuid": null,
                "validate_certs": false
            }
        },
        "item": "server1"
    },
    "msg": "server1 disk space is too high, it must be below 60GB"
}
ok: [local] => (item={'ansible_loop_var': 'item', 'changed': False, 'failed': False, 'guest_disk_info': {'0': {'backing_datastore': 'DatastoreA', 'backing_eagerlyscrub': False, 'backing_filename': '[DatastoreA] server2/server2.vmdk', 'backing_thinprovisioned': False, 'backing_type': 'FlatVer2', 'backing_uuid': '6000D296-4d2a-abf0-5d21-0cfcdf2498ad', 'backing_writethrough': False, 'capacity_in_bytes': 37580963840, 'capacity_in_kb': 36700160, 'controller_bus_number': 0, 'controller_key': 1000, 'controller_type': 'lsilogicsas', 'key': 2000, 'label': 'Hard disk 1', 'summary': '36,700,160 KB', 'unit_number': 0}}, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'datacenter': '/DatacenterA', 'folder': '/vm/server2', 'hostname': 'vmware.server.example.com', 'moid': None, 'name': 'server2', 'password': 'VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER', 'port': 443, 'proxy_host': None, 'proxy_port': None, 'use_instance_uuid': False, 'servername': 'server2', 'uuid': None, 'validate_certs': False}}, 'item': 'server2'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "guest_disk_info": {
            "0": {
                "backing_datastore": "DatastoreA",
                "backing_eagerlyscrub": false,
                "backing_filename": "[DatastoreA] server2/server2.vmdk",
                "backing_thinprovisioned": false,
                "backing_type": "FlatVer2",
                "backing_uuid": "6000D296-4d2a-abf0-5d21-0cfcdf2498ad",
                "backing_writethrough": false,
                "capacity_in_bytes": 37580963840,
                "capacity_in_kb": 36700160,
                "controller_bus_number": 0,
                "controller_key": 1000,
                "controller_type": "lsilogicsas",
                "key": 2000,
                "label": "Hard disk 1",
                "summary": "36,700,160 KB",
                "unit_number": 0
            }
        },
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "datacenter": "/DatacenterA",
                "folder": "/vm/server2",
                "hostname": "vmware.server.example.com",
                "moid": null,
                "name": "server2",
                "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "port": 443,
                "proxy_host": null,
                "proxy_port": null,
                "servername": "server2",
                "use_instance_uuid": false,
                "uuid": null,
                "validate_certs": false
            }
        },
        "item": "server2"
    },
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
local                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your quick help!! I am going to modify the play as per your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

That's double-plus ungood.

The hosts should be the VMs, not `localhost`.

Delegate the necessary tasks, such as `vmware_guest_disk_info`, to `localhost`.

Then you have all the host info right there at the `assert`.

```
---
- hosts: server1, server2, server3
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Gather disk info from guests
    vmware_guest_disk_info:
      hostname: "{{ vmwage_hostname }}"
      servername: "{{ vmware_servername }}"
      password: "{{ vmware_password }}"
      datacenter: DatacenterA
      validate_certs: no
      name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    register: disk_info
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: Show VMs with disk space more than 60 GB
    assert:
      that:
        - 'disk_info.guest_disk_info["0"].capacity_in_kb <= 62914560'
        - 'disk_info.guest_disk_info["0"].capacity_in_kb >= 0'
      fail_msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} Disk space is higher must be below 60"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I am going to modify the play as per your advise.